# Camera calibration: 3D to 2D points mapping

Tags: image, matlab, linear-algebra, camera-calibration

I am working on problem related to camera calibration. In the below image, we consider a world coordinate system with X-axis going leftward, Y-axis rightward and Z-axis upward. We select 15 points(x,y,z) distributed uniformly across the 3 planes. The distance between grid lines is 1 inch. We also obtain MATLAB coordinates for the 15 pixels(u,v). The objective is to obtain the 3x4 camera matrix (M) using homogeneous linear least squares and then project the world points (x,y,z) to the image (u',v') using M. I have written code to do this but the coordinates I'm obtaining (u',v') seem to be very small in magnitude compared to the actual coordinates (u,v). The RMS error is too large and the projected points don't even map onto the image anywhere near the actual points. Is there any scaling that I need to do to convert it to MATLAB coordinates? I am also including my code which isn't very well written since I am relatively new to MATLAB.
[image: Grid image]

```
P=[];% 2nx12 matrix - 30x12 matrix
for i=1:15 %compute P
    world_row = world_coords(i,:); % 3d homogeneous coordinates (x,y,z,1)
   zeroelem = repelem(0,4);
   image_coord = image_coords(i,:);
   img_u = image_coord(1);
   prod = -img_u*world_row;
   row1 = [world_row,zeroelem,prod];
   zeroelem = repelem(0,3);
   img_v = image_coord(2);
   prod = -img_v*world_row;
   row2 = [0,world_row,zeroelem,prod];
   P=[P;row1;row2];
  end
 var1 = P'*P;
 [V,D] = eig(var1');//compute eigen vector corresponding to least eigen  value
 m = V(:,1); //unit vector of norm 1
 M = reshape(m,3,4); //camera matrix of 3x4 size
 %get projected points
 proj = M*world_coords';
 U = proj (1,:);
 V = proj (2,:);
 W = proj (3,:);
 for i=1:15
  U(i) = U(i)/W(i);
  V(i) = V(i)/W(i);
 end
 final = [U;V];//(u',v')
```

[image: 15 points across the 3 planes]

I am also including the image with the 15 points I have selected. Take P1(u,v) = (286,260) and P1(x,y,z) = (4,0,3). The (u',v') I obtained for this has low values. Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly error from my me that was giving me the wrong camera matrix. I noted down the world coordinates of the point P wrongly ((7,0,1) instead of (1,0,1)). This led to wrongly formed 30x12 matrix which we use to form an equation to be solved by homogeneous linear least squares. I have obtained the calibration matrix which projects the 3D points with a low RMS error after correcting this mistake.
[image]